# Wordpress - Require username and password to view page

Tags: wordpress, locking

I need to lock one of my pages in WordPress 4.2.3 with a username and password so that the only people who can access it are the ones we email the username and password to.

Is there a way for me to do this..possibly without a plugin?

Comment: Why is this set as off topic. Can any of you admins explain that. Or do you just not care?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin...just mark the post visibility as "password protected" in the admin.

Read more about how to do this [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Setting_Page_and_Post_Visibility).

Comment: This is kinda what I need except it only locks the WordPress content. All the content on this page is done through a Custom Post Type and ACF's. It doesn't lock any of that. I'm thinking there might be a function I could create to lock that content. I don't know where to start though and those are plugins so I will get down voted even more if I ask about it. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I figured out how to do it from the WordPress Codex... <?php if ( !post_password_required() ) {  echo "the_field('myField')" } ?>   Thanks or getting me started.